# Import Error when starting server on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, python-import, importerror

I am deploying a python app to Google Cloud App Engine. After a successful deploy, the server starts automatically. Unfortunately, the startup fails and the logs show that an import error caused this crash. The module that is missing is basically a folder that, I created myself. I assume this is the issue.

I already googled and added `__init__.py` to all directories in my working space.

This is my main_admin.py file which is the entry point for gunicorn.

```
from projects.admin.initializer_admin import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This is the error, that I am receiving:

```
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py",
 line 350, 
in import_app      __import__(module)    File "/srv/main.py",
 line 1,in <module> from projects.admin.initializer_admin import app  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projects'
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: Can you show your directory structure?

Comment: Your directory structure and your custom entrypoint command would be useful to help debug.